# What is exactly a "Children" In a MDI app of C#? Problems with HasChildren

Tags: c#

I'm making an MDI App that Works like a text editor. I'm using a method that verifies that there is an MDI Children form existing to perform an "undo" action with HasChildren.

```
    private void undoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if(this.HasChildren)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Nobody said it was easy");

            myForm newMyForm =(myForm)this.ActiveMdiChild;
            newMyForm.Undo();
        }
    }
```

The problem is that HasChildren, after the execution of InitializeComponent() in the MDIForm is always true! I executed this code:

```
    public myMDIParent()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(HasChildren);
        InitializeComponent();
        Console.WriteLine(HasChildren);
        bool hasChildren =this.MdiChildren.Length==0;
        Console.WriteLine(hasChildren);
    }
```

And i get this output (i can't post images)

false
true 
true

So, why HasChildren is true if there is no Children Forms?

Comment: `HasChildren` is the number of child controls, not forms. Have you read the manual? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.haschildren%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Comment: I did, but i didn't understand. Thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

You can try this way to check if the "undo" form existed.

```
myForm newMyForm;
private void undoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(newMyForm == null)
    {
        newMyForm = new myForm();
        newMyForm.MdiParent = this;
        newMyForm.Show();
    }
    else
    {
        newMyForm.Activate();
        newMyForm.Undo();
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not trying to make a new Children form, I'm just trying to check if there is an existing children form in the MDI Parent form; so, if there is, i perform the Undo method when the Undo button is pressed (or ctrl+z). Anyway, thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 0):

Luckily, you don't need to check `HasChildren`.  Just look whether `ActiveMdiChild` is `null`:

```
private void undoToolStripMenuItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    myForm newMyForm = ActiveMdiChild as myForm;
    if (newMyForm != null) {
        Console.WriteLine("Nobody said it was easy");
        newMyForm.Undo();
    }
}
```

Comment: At last, my solution was to compare the Lenght of MDiChildren to 0. Even so, your solution is great! Thaks!